# Why auto-fit or auto-fill not working properly with minmax?

Tags: css, css-grid

It doesn't work properly when I add auto-fit or auto-fill instead of a number.

```
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, max-content));
```

[image]

But it works properly when I add number instead of max-content.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, max-content));
```

[image]

But I want the size of the grid to be the same(be fit) as the size of the content. Like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(30, minmax(max-content, max-content));
```

[image]

(using auto-fit or auto-fill). How can I do that?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, max-content));
 grid-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>dolor sit</li>
        <li>amet</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Comment: Simply because that's not an option supported by CSS-Grid. At least one of the "values" has to be a number. That's the spec - https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid-template-columns

Answer (score 10):

I recently came across this problem as well. From the [specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#funcdef-repeat)

> The generic form of the repeat() syntax is, approximately,
>
> repeat( `[ <positive-integer> | auto-fill | auto-fit ]` , `<track-list>`)
>   The first argument specifies the number of repetitions. The second argument is a track list, which is repeated that number of times. However, there are some restrictions:
>
> The repeat() notation can’t be nested.
>
> **Automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined with intrinsic or flexible sizes.**

After a few days of trying, it seems that **any** use of `min-content`, `max-content`, or `auto` in the repeat `<track-list>` will flat-out be ignored, even inside of `minmax`. Replacing one of them with a fixed-number works because it simply defaults to that.
I did manage to create a programmatic workaround using [ResizeSensor](https://github.com/procurios/ResizeSensor) and [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), though.

```js
var GRID_GAP = 3; // GRID-GAP of the grid
var iGridW = 0; // LAST comparative value of grid item width
var sizingWIP = false;
var GRID_LAYOUT = {
  'maxwidth': { /* CSS settings to compare item widths */
    display: "grid",
    gap: GRID_GAP + "px",
    "grid-template-columns": "none",
    "grid-auto-columns": "max-content"
  },
  'normal': { /* Normal CSS style to display the grid */
    display: "grid",
    gap: GRID_GAP + "px",
    "grid-template-columns": "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(" + iGridW + "px, 1fr)",
    "grid-auto-columns": "none"
  }
};

$(function() { // Shorthand for document.ready event
  evalGridItemMaxSize();
};

new ResizeSensor(document.getElementById("grdContainer"), function() {
  if(sizingWIP) return;
  sizingWIP = true;
  evalGridItemMaxSize();
  sizingWIP = false;
});


// EVALUATE GRID ITEM WIDTH TO MAX-CONTENT FOR *ALL* COLUMNS (equivalent to "grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, max-content)" which *cannot* be set in CSS
//    (repeat(auto-fill... & repeat(auto-fit... *cannot* be used with intrinsic {min-content, max-content, auto})
function evalGridItemMaxSize() {
  $("#grdSelector").css(GRID_LAYOUT['maxwidth']);
  if ($("#someGridItemID").outerWidth() === iGridW) {
    $("#grdSelector").css(GRID_LAYOUT['normal']);
    return; //Exit if grid item max-width is same as last time
  }

  // Re-evaluate grid item width as a function of max-content of *all* items
  iGridW = $("#someGridItemID").outerWidth();
  GRID_LAYOUT['normal']['grid-template-columns'] = "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(" + iGridW + "px, 1fr)"
  $("#grdSelector").css(GRID_LAYOUT['normal']);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/procurios/ResizeSensor/master/dist/resizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="grdContainer">
  <div class="grid-container" id="grdSelector">
    <!-- GRID ITEMS GO HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
```

`evalGridItemMaxSize()` sets the whole grid to a single column with size of `max-content` so all items will be as wide as the widest item. It then captures that width from one of the elements in the grid and recreates the columns by inserting that width (as a **fixed** number) into the `minmax` function in `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit...`.
Not sure if it's exactly what  you're looking for, but I was sure happy when I figured this out :) Hope it helps.
**NOTE: As I stated, this will size all columns to be the same** (minimum) **width as the widest element**

Answer (score 6):

At least one of the two arguments in a `minmax()` function must be a *fixed* length (e.g., px, em, %).

This rule is detailed in the Grid spec. See section "[The syntax of a track list](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)".

That's why your code (copied below) is not working.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, max-content));
```

---

In solving the problem I thought this other Grid rule would come in handy:

> [***`minmax(min, max)`***](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#valdef-grid-template-columns-minmax)
>
> Defines a size range greater than or equal to min and less than or
>   equal to max.
>
> *If max < min, then max is ignored and `minmax(min,max)` is treated as min.*

Looking at that last line, if max is less than min, then min prevails.

Looking at the first rule, at least one argument must be a fixed length.

So then this should work:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 1px));
```

It actually does fix the problem... but it also breaks the `auto-fit` wrapping feature ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zb26Lexg/7/)).

Nothing else I tried seemed to work. Maybe somebody else can find a solution. Or maybe this is a limitation in the current iteration of Grid.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the wrapping to new line feature?

Answer (score -2):

Do `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 0))`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
 display: grid;
 width:50px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 0));
 grid-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>dolor sit</li>
        <li>amet</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

[image]

Comment: This does not solve the OP's issue. Remove the *forced* width and see. The elements don't wrap.

Answer (score -3):

Add some width (in this example I added 'width: 100vw;' to 'ul' tag) to a tag you want a 'repeat' to apply.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
 width: 100vw;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
 grid-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>dolor sit</li>
        <li>amet</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
        <li>word</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

Add some width to a tag you want a 'repeat', 'min-max' to apply.