# Mixing fixed length and repeat() in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a calendar using a grid layout. Each day of the week will have a header.  My goal is to set the height of the header (ie: the first row in the grid) to 30px, and have the rest of the rows split the rest of the available space.

My calendar CSS looks like this:

```
.calendar{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(1,1fr);
    grid-template-rows:30px repeat(auto-fill,1fr);
}
```

Now, I *thought* that would do exactly what I want, but that `30px` has no effect, and each row is an equal height.  Is it possible to mix a static value and `repeat()`?

I realize I can just make 2 grids - one for the headers and one for the days - but I'm curious if there's a way cleaner way.

Demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGEaOm

```css
.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr);
}


/** Appearance styles that don't affect the layout */
.calendar {
  min-height: 200px;
}
.day {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="day">
    First
  </div>
  <div class="day">
    Second
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short Answer

Instead of:

```
grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)
```

Try this:

```
grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr))
```

```css
.calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10px, 1fr));
  grid-row-gap: 2px;
}

/** Appearance styles that don't affect the layout */
.calendar {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.day {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="day">First</div>
  <div class="day">Second</div>
</div>
```

---

### Explanation

Note this rule in your code:

```
grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)
```

This rule is invalid.

[image]

It is, therefore, ignored by the browser and [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) falls back to its default setting: `none` (which means all rows will be implicitly created and sized by [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows), who's default value is `auto`).

*From the spec:*

> [§ 7.2. Explicit Track Sizing: the `grid-template-rows` and
>   `grid-template-columns`
>   properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)
>
> The ***`none`*** value.
>
> Indicates that no explicit grid tracks are created by this property
>   (though explicit grid tracks could still be created by
>   `grid-template-areas`).
>
> > Note: In the absence of an explicit grid any rows/columns will be
> >     implicitly generated, and their size will be determined by the
> >     `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns` properties.

**The main problem** is that `auto-fill` (and `auto-fit`) cannot be combined with *intrinsic* or *flexible* lengths, such as `auto`, `min-content` or `fr`.

> [§ 7.2.2.1. Syntax of
>   `repeat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-syntax)
>
> - Automatic repetitions (`auto-fill` or `auto-fit`) cannot be combined
>     with **intrinsic** or **flexible** sizes.
>
> [§ 11. Grid
>   Sizing](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#layout-algorithm)
>
> - An intrinsic sizing function is `min-content`, `max-content`, `auto` and `fit-content()`).
> - A flexible sizing function [is a dimension with the `fr` unit](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit).

Therefore, because your rule (`(auto-fill, 1fr)`) contains `auto-fill` with a flexible sizing function (`fr`), it cannot work.

**A solution** may be to work around the problem with `minmax()`.

Instead of:

```
grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fill, 1fr)
```

Try this:

```
grid-template-rows: 30px repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10px, 1fr))
```

---

More details:

- [What is the difference between auto-fill and auto-fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46226539/3597276)
- [minmax fails (invalid property value)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45333922/3597276)
- [Why auto-fit or auto-fill not working properly with minmax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51594965/3597276)

Comment: Ooohhh, so it wasn't the combination of "30px" and "repeat()" that was causing the problem, it was the combination of "auto-fill" and "1fr".  Thanks for the answer.